# Информация про клавиатуру и мышь C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Задача сделать аналог **AIDA** или **Speccy**, но более упрощенный.
Делаю на **С#**, Windows Forms используя **Environment**, **реестр** и **DriveInfo**.

Возникли трудности с выводом инфы о мышке и клавиатуре. Хочу отображать в **TextBox** хотя бы то, что они подключены, но понятия не имею, где искать это. Были мысли, что есть в реестре имя, которое хранит какое то значение 1 или 0, что они подключены.

Вопрос таков: Где искать информацию о том, что с ПК подключены мышка и клавиатура.

---

[image: Программа в рабочем состоянии(черновик)]

P.S Приложение должно работать на разных ПК или ноутбука с ОС Win7 и выше

Answer (score 3):

В References проекта установите ссылку на `System.Management`.
В том классе где будете работать пропишите `using System.Management;`
Пример консольной программы:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HasDevice("PointingDevice"));
        Console.WriteLine(HasDevice("Keyboard"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool HasDevice(string typeDevice)
    {
        var mObjects = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_" + typeDevice);


        //выводим разнообразную информацию об устройствах
        var devices = (from ManagementObject d in mObjects.Get() as ManagementObjectCollection
                   select d);

        foreach (var item in devices)
        {
            foreach (var p in item.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}==>{p.Value}");
            }
        }

        //определяем подключено ли устройство
        var result = (from ManagementObject d in mObjects.Get() as ManagementObjectCollection
                   where d.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString() == "OK"
                   select d).First();
        //выводим результат
        return result != null;
    }
```

Comment: Хорошо.Попробую. Спасибо